# Problema con diseño responsivo de formulario

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap

Tengo un problema con el formulario al hacer las pruebas de los atributos responsivos (estoy usando una plantilla prediseñada) el formulario se sobrepone a otros elementos de la pagina antes de adecuarse al tamaño necesario. El header lo estoy importando y ya incluye la parte del sidebar menu, estoy trabajando con varios formularios pero todos tienen el mismo problema, he probado cambiar los valores de los col-md y tambien he revisado si los elementos esten fuera de los div. Soy nueva haciendo esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**CODIGO CSS**

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ruda:400,700,900);

body {
    color: #797979;
 background: #F7F7F7;
    font-family: 'Ruda', sans-serif;
    padding: 0px !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    font-size:13px;
}

ul li {
    list-style: none;
}

a, a:hover, a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
}
::selection {

    background: #115173;
    color: #fff;
}
::-moz-selection {
    background: #E7BF5F;
    color: #fff;
}

#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/* Bootstrap Modifications */
.modal-header {
 background: #115173;
}

.modal-title {
 color: white;
}

.btn-round {
 border-radius: 20px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
}

.accordion-heading .accordion-toggle {
 display: block;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-top: 1px solid #F5F5F5;
 padding: 5px 0px;
 line-height: 28.75px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 color: #1a1a1a;
 background-color: #ffffff;
 outline: none !important;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.btn-theme {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #E7BF5F;
  border-color: #E7BF5F;
}
.btn-theme:hover,
.btn-theme:focus,
.btn-theme:active,
.btn-theme.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-theme {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #74777B;
  border-color: #74777B;
}

/*Exclusive Theme Colors Configuration*/

.label-theme {
 background-color: #4ECDC4;
}

.bg-theme {
 background-color: #4ECDC4;
}

ul.top-menu > li > .logout {
 color: #000;
 font-size: 12px;
 border-radius: 4px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
 border: 1px solid #ffe36e !important;
 padding: 5px 15px;
 margin-right: 15px;
 background: #ffe36e;
 margin-top: 15px;
}

/*BOOTSTRAP*/

.panel{margin-bottom:20px;background-color:#fff;border:1px solid transparent;border-radius:4px;-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);box-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05)}.panel-body{padding:15px}.panel-heading{padding:10px 15px;border-bottom:1px solid transparent;border-top-left-radius:3px;border-top-right-radius:3px}.panel-heading>.dropdown .dropdown-toggle{color:inherit}.panel-title{margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;font-size:16px;color:inherit}.panel-title>.small,.panel-title>.small>a,.panel-title>a,.panel-title>small,.panel-title>small>a{color:inherit}.panel-footer{padding:10px 15px;background-color:#f5f5f5;border-top:1px solid #ddd;border-bottom-right-radius:3px;border-bottom-left-radius:3px}.panel>.list-group,.panel>.panel-collapse>.list-group{margin-bottom:0}.panel>.list-group .list-group-item,.panel>.panel-collapse>.list-group .list-group-item{border-width:1px 0;border-radius:0}.panel>.list-group:first-child .list-group-item:first-child,.panel>.panel-collapse>.list-group:first-child .list-group-item:first-child{border-top:0;border-top-left-radius:3px;border-top-right-radius:3px}.panel>.list-group:last-child .list-group-item:last-child,.panel>.panel-collapse>.list-group:last-child .list-group-item:last-child{border-bottom:0;border-bottom-right-radius:3px;border-bottom-left-radius:3px}.panel>.panel-heading+.panel-collapse>.list-group .list-group-item:first-child{border-top-left-radius:0;border-top-right-radius:0}.panel-heading+.list-group .list-group-item:first-child{border-top-width:0}.list-group+.panel-footer{border-top-width:0}.panel>.panel-collapse>.table,.panel>.table,.panel>.table-responsive>.table{margin-bottom:0}.panel>.panel-collapse>.table caption,.panel>.table caption,.panel>.table-responsive>.table caption{padding-right:15px;padding-left:15px}.panel>.table-responsive:first-child>.table:first-child,.panel>.table:first-child{border-top-left-radius:3px;border-top-right-radius:3px}.panel>.table-responsive:first-child>.table:first-child>tbody:first-child>tr:first-child,.panel>.table-responsive:first-child>.table:first-child>thead:first-child>tr:first-child,.panel>.table:first-child>tbody:first-child>tr:first-child,.panel>.table:first-child>thead:first-child>tr:first-child{border-top-left-radius:3px;border-top-right-radius:3px}.panel>.table-responsive:first-child>.table:first-child>tbody:first-child>tr:first-child td:first-child,.panel>.table-responsive:first-child>.table:first-child>tbody:first-child>tr:first-child th:first-child,.panel>.table-responsive:first-child>.table:first-child>thead:first-child>tr:first-child td:first-child,.panel>.table-responsive:first-child>.table:first-child>thead:first-child>tr:first-child th:first-child,.panel>.table:first-child>tbody:first-child>tr:first-child td:first-child,.panel>.table:first-child>tbody:first-child>tr:first-child th:first-child,.panel>.table:first-child>thead:first-child>tr:first-child td:first-child,.panel>.table:first-child>thead:first-child>tr:first-child th:first-child{border-top-left-radius:3px}.panel>.table-responsive:first-child>.table:first-child>tbody:first-child>tr:first-child td:last-child,.panel>.table-responsive:first-child>.table:first-child>tbody:first-child>tr:first-child th:last-child,.panel>.table-responsive:first-child>.table:first-child>thead:first-child>tr:first-child td:last-child,.panel>.table-responsive:first-child>.table:first-child>thead:first-child>tr:first-child th:last-child,.panel>.table:first-child>tbody:first-child>tr:first-child td:last-child,.panel>.table:first-child>tbody:first-child>tr:first-child th:last-child,.panel>.table:first-child>thead:first-child>tr:first-child td:last-child,.panel>.table:first-child>thead:first-child>tr:first-child th:last-child{border-top-right-radius:3px}.panel>.table-responsive:last-child>.table:last-child,.panel>.table:last-child{border-bottom-right-radius:3px;border-bottom-left-radius:3px}.panel>.table-responsive:last-child>.table:last-child>tbody:last-child>tr:last-child,.panel>.table-responsive:last-child>.table:last-child>tfoot:last-child>tr:last-child,.panel>.table:last-child>tbody:last-child>tr:last-child,.panel>.table:last-child>tfoot:last-child>tr:last-child{border-bottom-right-radius:3px;border-bottom-left-radius:3px}.panel>.table-responsive:last-child>.table:last-child>tbody:last-child>tr:last-child td:first-child,.panel>.table-responsive:last-child>.table:last-child>tbody:last-child>tr:last-child th:first-child,.panel>.table-responsive:last-child>.table:last-child>tfoot:last-child>tr:last-child td:first-child,.panel>.table-responsive:last-child>.table:last-child>tfoot:last-child>tr:last-child th:first-child,.panel>.table:last-child>tbody:last-child>tr:last-child td:first-child,.panel>.table:last-child>tbody:last-child>tr:last-child th:first-child,.panel>.table:last-child>tfoot:last-child>tr:last-child td:first-child,.panel>.table:last-child>tfoot:last-child>tr:last-child th:first-child{border-bottom-left-radius:3px}.panel>.table-responsive:last-child>.table:last-child>tbody:last-child>tr:last-child td:last-child,.panel>.table-responsive:last-child>.table:last-child>tbody:last-child>tr:last-child th:last-child,.panel>.table-responsive:last-child>.table:last-child>tfoot:last-child>tr:last-child td:last-child,.panel>.table-responsive:last-child>.table:last-child>tfoot:last-child>tr:last-child th:last-child,.panel>.table:last-child>tbody:last-child>tr:last-child td:last-child,.panel>.table:last-child>tbody:last-child>tr:last-child th:last-child,.panel>.table:last-child>tfoot:last-child>tr:last-child td:last-child,.panel>.table:last-child>tfoot:last-child>tr:last-child th:last-child{border-bottom-right-radius:3px}.panel>.panel-body+.table,.panel>.panel-body+.table-responsive,.panel>.table+.panel-body,.panel>.table-responsive+.panel-body{border-top:1px solid #ddd}.panel>.table>tbody:first-child>tr:first-child td,.panel>.table>tbody:first-child>tr:first-child th{border-top:0}.panel>.table-bordered,.panel>.table-responsive>.table-bordered{border:0}.panel>.table-bordered>tbody>tr>td:first-child,.panel>.table-bordered>tbody>tr>th:first-child,.panel>.table-bordered>tfoot>tr>td:first-child,.panel>.table-bordered>tfoot>tr>th:first-child,.panel>.table-bordered>thead>tr>td:first-child,.panel>.table-bordered>thead>tr>th:first-child,.panel>.table-responsive>.table-bordered>tbody>tr>td:first-child,.panel>.table-responsive>.table-bordered>tbody>tr>th:first-child,.panel>.table-responsive>.table-bordered>tfoot>tr>td:first-child,.panel>.table-responsive>.table-bordered>tfoot>tr>th:first-child,.panel>.table-responsive>.table-bordered>thead>tr>td:first-child,.panel>.table-responsive>.table-bordered>thead>tr>th:first-child{border-left:0}.panel>.table-bordered>tbody>tr>td:last-child,.panel>.table-bordered>tbody>tr>th:last-child,.panel>.table-bordered>tfoot>tr>td:last-child,.panel>.table-bordered>tfoot>tr>th:last-child,.panel>.table-bordered>thead>tr>td:last-child,.panel>.table-bordered>thead>tr>th:last-child,.panel>.table-responsive>.table-bordered>tbody>tr>td:last-child,.panel>.table-responsive>.table-bordered>tbody>tr>th:last-child,.panel>.table-responsive>.table-bordered>tfoot>tr>td:last-child,.panel>.table-responsive>.table-bordered>tfoot>tr>th:last-child,.panel>.table-responsive>.table-bordered>thead>tr>td:last-child,.panel>.table-responsive>.table-bordered>thead>tr>th:last-child{border-right:0}.panel>.table-bordered>tbody>tr:first-child>td,.panel>.table-bordered>tbody>tr:first-child>th,.panel>.table-bordered>thead>tr:first-child>td,.panel>.table-bordered>thead>tr:first-child>th,.panel>.table-responsive>.table-bordered>tbody>tr:first-child>td,.panel>.table-responsive>.table-bordered>tbody>tr:first-child>th,.panel>.table-responsive>.table-bordered>thead>tr:first-child>td,.panel>.table-responsive>.table-bordered>thead>tr:first-child>th{border-bottom:0}.panel>.table-bordered>tbody>tr:last-child>td,.panel>.table-bordered>tbody>tr:last-child>th,.panel>.table-bordered>tfoot>tr:last-child>td,.panel>.table-bordered>tfoot>tr:last-child>th,.panel>.table-responsive>.table-bordered>tbody>tr:last-child>td,.panel>.table-responsive>.table-bordered>tbody>tr:last-child>th,.panel>.table-responsive>.table-bordered>tfoot>tr:last-child>td,.panel>.table-responsive>.table-bordered>tfoot>tr:last-child>th{border-bottom:0}.panel>.table-responsive{margin-bottom:0;border:0}.panel-group{margin-bottom:20px}.panel-group .panel{margin-bottom:0;border-radius:4px}.panel-group .panel+.panel{margin-top:5px}.panel-group .panel-heading{border-bottom:0}.panel-group .panel-heading+.panel-collapse>.list-group,.panel-group .panel-heading+.panel-collapse>.panel-body{border-top:1px solid #ddd}.panel-group .panel-footer{border-top:0}.panel-group .panel-footer+.panel-collapse .panel-body{border-bottom:1px solid #ddd}.panel-default{border-color:#ddd}.panel-default>.panel-heading{color:#333;background-color:#f5f5f5;border-color:#ddd}.panel-default>.panel-heading+.panel-collapse>.panel-body{border-top-color:#ddd}.panel-default>.panel-heading .badge{color:#f5f5f5;background-color:#333}.panel-default>.panel-footer+.panel-collapse>.panel-body{border-bottom-color:#ddd}.panel-primary{border-color:#022c43}.panel-primary>.panel-heading{color:#fff;background-color:#022c43;border-color:#022c43}.panel-primary>.panel-heading+.panel-collapse>.panel-body{border-top-color:#022c43}.panel-primary>.panel-heading .badge{color:#022c43;background-color:#fff}.panel-primary>.panel-footer+.panel-collapse>.panel-body{border-bottom-color:#022c43}.panel-success{border-color:#d6e9c6}.panel-success>.panel-heading{color:#3c763d;background-color:#dff0d8;border-color:#d6e9c6}.panel-success>.panel-heading+.panel-collapse>.panel-body{border-top-color:#d6e9c6}.panel-success>.panel-heading .badge{color:#dff0d8;background-color:#3c763d}.panel-success>.panel-footer+.panel-collapse>.panel-body{border-bottom-color:#d6e9c6}.panel-info{border-color:#bce8f1}.panel-info>.panel-heading{color:#31708f;background-color:#d9edf7;border-color:#bce8f1}.panel-info>.panel-heading+.panel-collapse>.panel-body{border-top-color:#bce8f1}.panel-info>.panel-heading .badge{color:#d9edf7;background-color:#31708f}.panel-info>.panel-footer+.panel-collapse>.panel-body{border-bottom-color:#bce8f1}.panel-warning{border-color:#faebcc}.panel-warning>.panel-heading{color:#8a6d3b;background-color:#fcf8e3;border-color:#faebcc}.panel-warning>.panel-heading+.panel-collapse>.panel-body{border-top-color:#faebcc}.panel-warning>.panel-heading .badge{color:#fcf8e3;background-color:#8a6d3b}.panel-warning>.panel-footer+.panel-collapse>.panel-body{border-bottom-color:#faebcc}.panel-danger{border-color:#ebccd1}.panel-danger>.panel-heading{color:#a94442;background-color:#f2dede;border-color:#ebccd1}.panel-danger>.panel-heading+.panel-collapse>.panel-body{border-top-color:#ebccd1}.panel-danger>.panel-heading .badge{color:#f2dede;background-color:#a94442}.panel-danger>.panel-footer+.panel-collapse>.panel-body{border-bottom-color:#ebccd1}

**HTML**
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-20 col-md-offset-2">
       <div class="panel panel-primary">
         <div class="panel-heading"> 
             <center><h3>Recursos Humanos Capacitacion Certificaciones</h3></center></div>
      <div class="panel-body" >
          <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" 
               action="personas_guardar.php">
                  
      <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Fecha de Capacitacion
                        </label>
   <div class="col-md-6"> 
   <input type="date" name="fechadecapacitacion" 
                          class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
   <!---------------------------------------------------------------->
      <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Nombre de Capacitador
                        </label>
   <div class="col-md-6"> 
     <input type="text" name="nombredecapacitacion" 
                            class="form-control">
           </div>
       </div>
   <!---------------------------------------------------------------->
            <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Programa
                        </label>
   <div class="col-md-6"> 
     <input type="text" name="programa" 
                            class="form-control">
           </div>
       </div>

   <!---------------------------------------------------------------->
      <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Instalación donde se lleva a cabo
                        </label>
   <div class="col-md-6"> 
     <input type="text" name="dependientes" 
                            class="form-control">
           </div>
    </div>
   <!---------------------------------------------------------------->
   <div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Evidencia Fotografíca
                        </label>
   <div class="col-md-6"> 
     <input type="text" name="evidenciafotografica" 
                            class="form-control">
           </div>
    </div>
            <!---------------------------------------------------------------->
   <!-----buttons---------------------------------------------------->
       <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
   <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary">Guardar 
                        </button> 
   <a type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
                          href="index.php">Cancelar</a>
    </div>
    <!--form end------>
   </form>
   <!---div end--->
             </div>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
  </div>
<!---body end-->
 <body>
<!---html end-->
</html>
```

**Codigo del Header**

```js
function myNavFunction(id) {
      $("#date-popover").hide();
      var nav = $("#" + id).data("navigation");
      var to = $("#" + id).data("to");
      console.log('nav ' + nav + ' to: ' + to.month + '/' + to.year);
    }
```

```css
/*sidebar navigation*/

#sidebar {
    width: 210px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background: #2f323a;
}

#sidebar h5 {
 color: #f2f2f2;
 font-weight: 700;
}

#sidebar ul li {
    position: relative;
}

#sidebar .sub-menu > .sub li  {
    padding-left: 32px;
}

#sidebar .sub-menu > .sub li:last-child {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

/*LEFT NAVIGATION ICON*/
.dcjq-icon {
    height:17px;
    width:17px;
    display:inline-block;
    background: url("../img/nav-expand.png") no-repeat top;
    border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    top:15px;
}
.active .dcjq-icon {
    background: url("../img/nav-expand.png") no-repeat bottom;
    border-radius:3px;
    -moz-border-radius:3px;
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
}
/*---*/

.nav-collapse.collapse {
    display: inline;
}

ul.sidebar-menu , ul.sidebar-menu li ul.sub{
    margin: -2px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul.sidebar-menu {
    margin-top: 75px;
}

#sidebar > ul > li > ul.sub {
    display: none;
}

#sidebar > ul > li.active > ul.sub, #sidebar > ul > li > ul.sub > li > a {
    display: block;
}

ul.sidebar-menu li ul.sub li{
    background: #2f323a;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}

ul.sidebar-menu li ul.sub li:last-child{
    border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
}

ul.sidebar-menu li ul.sub li a {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 6px 0;
    line-height: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    color: #aeb2b7;
}

ul.sidebar-menu li ul.sub li a:hover {
 color: white;
 background: transparent;
}

ul.sidebar-menu li ul.sub li.active a {
    color: #4ECDC4;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    display: block;
}

ul.sidebar-menu li{
    /*line-height: 20px !important;*/
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-right:10px;
}

ul.sidebar-menu li.sub-menu{
    line-height: 15px;
}

ul.sidebar-menu li a span{
    display: inline-block;
}

ul.sidebar-menu li a{
    color: #aeb2b7;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 0 15px 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    outline: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

ul.sidebar-menu li a.active, ul.sidebar-menu li a:hover, ul.sidebar-menu li a:focus {
    background: #ffe36e;
    color: #000;
    display: block;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}


ul.sidebar-menu li a i {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-right: 6px;
}

ul.sidebar-menu li a:hover i, ul.sidebar-menu li a:focus i {
    color: #000;
}

ul.sidebar-menu li a.active i {
    color: #000;
}

/* MAIN CONTENT CONFIGURATION */
#main-content {
    margin-left: 210px;
}

.header, .footer {
    min-height: 60px;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.header {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1002;
}

.black-bg {
    background: #22242a;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #393d46;
}

.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 60px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

a.logo {
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

a.logo b {
    font-weight: 900;
}

a.logo:hover, a.logo:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
}

a.logo span {
    color: #E7BF5F;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="Dashboard">
  <meta name="keyword" content="Dashboard, Bootstrap, Admin, Template, Theme, Responsive, Fluid, Retina">
  <title>Blak Box</title>

  <!-- Favicons -->
  <link href="../img/favicon.png" rel="icon">
  <link href="../img/apple-touch-icon.png" rel="apple-touch-icon">

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="../lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--external css-->
  <link href="../lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/zabuto_calendar.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../lib/gritter/css/jquery.gritter.css" />
  <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
  <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="../css/style-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="../lib/chart-master/Chart.js"></script>

   </head>
    <body>
      <section id="container">
      <!--header start-->
        <header class="header black-bg">
        <div class="sidebar-toggle-box">
        <div class="fa fa-bars tooltips" data-placement="right" data-original-title="Toggle Navigation"></div>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src="../img/logo-01-blakbox.png" align="right" width="110" height="20">
      </div>

      
          <div class="top-menu">
            <ul class="nav pull-right top-menu">
             <li><a class="logout" href="../classes/cerrarSesion.php">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </header>
    <!--header end-->
    
    <!--sidebar start-->
    <aside>
      <div id="sidebar" class="nav-collapse">
        <!-- sidebar menu start-->
        <ul class="sidebar-menu" id="nav-accordion">
          <p class="centered"><a href="#"><img src="../img/ui-sam.jpg" class="img-circle" width="80"></a></p>
          <h5 class="centered">Sam Soffes</h5>
          <li class="mt">
            <a class="active" href='../home.php'>
              <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o"></i>
              <span>Dashboard</span>
              </a>
          </li>
          <li class="sub-menu">
            <a href="javascript:;">
              <i class="fa fa-desktop"></i>
              <span>Recursos Humanos</span>
              </a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href='../RecursosHumanos/RHPEA.php'>RHPEA</a></li>
              <li><a href='../RecursosHumanos/RHPEAD.php'>RHPEAD</a></li>
              <li><a href='../RecursosHumanos/RHPEB.php'>RHPEB</a></li>
              <li><a href='../RecursosHumanos/RHSP.php'>RHSP</a></li>
              <li><a href='../RecursosHumanos/RHSPT.php'>RHSPT</a></li>
              <li><a href='../RecursosHumanos/RHSE.php'>RHSE</a></li>
              <li><a href='../RecursosHumanos/RHCC.php'>RHCC</a></li>
              <li><a href='../RecursosHumanos/RHDA.php'>RHDA</a></li>
              <li><a href='../RecursosHumanos/RHDP.php'>RHDP</a></li>
              <li><a href='../RecursosHumanos/RHDPP.php'>RHDPP</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="sub-menu">
            <a href="javascript:;">
              <i class="fa fa-book"></i>
              <span>Recursos Materiales</span>
              </a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
              <li><a href="../RecursosMateriales/RMVA.php">RMVA</a></li>
              <li><a href="../RecursosMateriales/RMVM.php">RMVM</a></li>
              <li><a href="../RecursosMateriales/RMVER.php">RMVER</a></li>
              <li><a href="../RecursosMateriales/RMA.php">RMA</a></li>
              <li><a href="../RecursosMateriales/RMUI.php">RMUI</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="sub-menu">
            <a href="javascript:;">
              <i class="fa fa-tasks"></i>
              <span>Supervision Operativa</span>
              </a>
            <ul class="sub">
              <li><a href="../SupervisionOperativa/SOUA.php">SOUA</a></li>
              <li><a href="../SupervisionOperativa/SOUER.php">SOUER</a></li>
              <li><a href="../SupervisionOperativa/SOUAN.php">SOUAN</a></li>
              <li><a href="../SupervisionOperativa/SORC.php">SORC</a></li>
              <li><a href="../SupervisionOperativa/SORAA.php">SORAA</a></li>
              <li><a href="../SupervisionOperativa/SORIA.php">SORIA</a></li>
              <li><a href="../SupervisionOperativa/SORED.php">SORED</a></li>
              <li><a href="../SupervisionOperativa/SORAN.php">SORAN</a></li>
              <li><a href="../SupervisionOperativa/SORMO.php">SORMO</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="sub-menu">
            <a href="javascript:;">
              <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
              <span>Area Comercial</span>
              </a>
            <ul class="sub">
              <li><a href="../AreaComercial/ACS.php">ACS</a></li>
              <li><a href="../AreaComercial/ACSA.php">ACSA</a></li>
              <li><a href="../AreaComercial/ACCS.php">ACCS</a></li>
              <li><a href="../AreaComercial/ACSAI.php">ACSAI</a></li>
              <li><a href="../AreaComercial/ACIC.php">ACIC</a></li>
              <li><a href="../AreaComercial/ACES.php">ACES</a></li>
              <li><a href="../AreaComercial/ACMC.php">ACMC</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- sidebar menu end-->
      </div>
    </aside>
    <!--sidebar end--> 
 <!-- js placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<!-- js placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
  <script src="../lib/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../lib/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.7.js"></script>
  <script src="../lib/jquery.scrollTo.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../lib/jquery.nicescroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="../lib/jquery.sparkline.js"></script>
  <!--common script for all pages-->
  <script src="../lib/common-scripts.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/gritter/js/jquery.gritter.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/gritter-conf.js"></script>
  <!--script for this page-->
  <script src="../lib/sparkline-chart.js"></script>
  <script src="../lib/zabuto_calendar.js"></script>

 
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

*Ya hice el cambio de col-20 a col-12 y ahora quedo de la siguiente manera*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sería bueno que compartieras el código completo (incluyendo el sidebar) de esta manera podríamos debuggear el código contigo. Con respecto al código, veo un error debajo del `<row>` en el cual tienes **col-md-20**, cambialo a **col-md-12** ya que bootstrap no tiene esa clase asignada a ninguna propiedad. Revisa a ver si de repente es eso lo que causa tu error.

Comment: ya agregue la parte del header, adjunte la pantalla despues de hacer el cambio a col-12.